# Using Tooleap SDK with Basic4Android

Tags: android, multitasking, floating, basic4android, tooleap

I've been trying to make an app with a floating window (multitasking capabilities). recently I ran into an SDK that allows me to create floating apps called [Tooleap](http://www.tooleap.com).

I've gone over their documentation. My problem is that i'm developing my app using Basic4Android. The Tooleap SDK documentation states that I need to extend my Activity class in order to create floating apps:

http://developer.tooleap.com/javadoc/com/tooleap/sdk/TooleapActivities.html

In other words, I want to achieve the following thing:

```
public class MyActivity extends TooleapActivities.Activity {

    // Activity Code...
}
```

Is that possible in Basic4Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible! (Why did you not post this on the B4A forums :) )

I wrote a wrapper and also a sample on how to use Tooleap with B4A. There are also links to tutorials on that post.
Have a look here: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/tooleap-library-floating-notifications-and-miniapps.41136/

Or here: http://habeebq.wordpress.com/category/tooleap-2/